# Activity name attribute not defined in Android Manifest file

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, android-manifest

I'm trying to add KeyboardAwareScrollView to my React-Native Android project and in order to implement it I have to add the following to the AndroidManifest.XML file:

```
<application ... >
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" ... />
</application>
```

However I can't complete my build as I keep getting the following error - " **'name' attribute should be defined** ", even though I have added the below code to my manifest file:

[AndroidManifest.XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khsaA.png)

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, you haven't specified the name for activity.

```
<activity android:name=:"X.Y.Z" .....etc>
```